# Changing xarray variable to dimension

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-xarray

I currently have the dataset

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (hybrid: 50, y: 1059, x: 1799)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] ...
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
  * hybrid      (hybrid) float64 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 ... 47.0 48.0 49.0 50.0
    latitude    (y, x) float64 ...
    longitude   (y, x) float64 -122.7 -122.7 -122.7 ... -60.99 -60.95 -60.92
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Data variables: (12/17)
    pres        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    clwmr       (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    gh          (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    rwmr        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    snmr        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    grle        (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    ...          ...
    t           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    q           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    u           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    v           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    w           (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
    tke         (hybrid, y, x) float32 ...
```

Instead of having hybrid, y, and x as dimensions, I want to set the data variable "gh" as a dimension and coordinate, as well as incorporate latitude and longitude into the dimensions. In other words, I want to make the dimensions of all the other data variables (gh, latitude, longitude) instead of (hybrid, y, x).

I'm very new to xarray; how do I do this?

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't really make sense. Dimensions are one-dimensional, corresponding to axes in your underlying numpy arrays. Therefore latitude and longitude (which are both 2D) can't be dimensions. There is a similar problem with gh. Overall it looks to me like your dataset is structured in a reasonable way, so it would be useful to know why you want to restructure your dataset like this.

Comment: In this case, I believe latitude and longitude are 2D because they are on a curvilinear grid. I want to restructure the dataset so that it is on a rectangular lat/lon grid (thus latitude and longitude would only need to be 1D) for consistency with other datasets I am using. I also want gh (geopotential height) as a dimension because I need to extract values for other variables at specific heights.